# SQL How to use CASE WHEN query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to get the date_closed depending upon the colour condition.

> -->If the colour code is green, the date closed should appear from the time stamp
>
> -->if the colour code is other than green the date close should be null.

To do this, I wrote the following query:

```
(CASE 
 WHEN A.C_STATUS = 'RD' THEN 'NULL' 
 ELSE (CASE WHEN A.C_STATUS = 'GR' THEN (F.T_TIMESTAMP) END) 
END) AS DATE_CLOSED
```

This is giving me an error stating that NULL cannot be in the date. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Its not working.. i used both the queries which you have suggested. All the values of date closed is appearing as null irrespective of the condition. But where as it is working if i give it like this.. (CASE WHEN A.C_STATUS='GR" THEN 1 END) AS DATE CLOSED. SO for this i am gettig the value as 1 for the rows which have status as green.. but when i replace the 1 with timestamp all the rows are coming null

Answer (score 5):

Putting quotes around the word 'NULL' means that you are trying to insert a string, which just happens to contain a word that you know is supposed to mean NULL.  What you actually have to do is say it without the quotes, which SQL Server will then recognize as NULL and not "some string with letters in it"

```
(CASE 
 WHEN A.C_STATUS = 'RD' THEN NULL
 ELSE (CASE WHEN A.C_STATUS = 'GR' THEN (F.T_TIMESTAMP) END) 
END) AS DATE_CLOSED
```

As a fun fact, if you leave off the ELSE statement anything that doesn't fit your CASE will automatically return NULL. Reading over your requirements, it actually looks like you are overcomplicating this code:  I believe the following will return the same results.

```
 CASE WHEN A.C_STATUS = 'GR' THEN F.T_TIMESTAMP END AS DATE_CLOSED
```

Comment: +1. You can make the `case` function match the spec more directly by making things explicit: `select case when a.C_STATUS = 'GR' then f.T_TIMESTAMP else null end as DATE_CLOSED ...`

Comment: Its not working.. i used both the queries which you have suggested. All the values of date closed is appearing as null irrespective of the condition. But where as it is working if i give it like this.. (CASE WHEN A.C_STATUS='GR" THEN 1 END) AS DATE CLOSED. SO for this i am gettig the value as 1 for the rows which have status as green.. but when i replace the 1 with timestamp all the rows are coming null

Comment: OK, so the obvious question here is what value is in the Timestamp field?  You have aliases in your CASE statement which make it seem that the T_TIMESTAMP and C_STATUS columns are on different tables: what is the JOIN condition between them, and are you sure that a TIMESTAMP value actually exists for the rows you are looking at?  Edit your original question with the full SQL of your SELECT statement, and if possible also include some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

you can also write your case statement as

```
(
  CASE 
    WHEN A.C_STATUS = 'RD' THEN NULL
    WHEN A.C_STATUS = 'GR' THEN (F.T_TIMESTAMP)
 ELSE 
 END
)AS DATE_CLOSED
```

NOTE :  this is the SQL statement.Not sure about Oracle but it should be same .

Comment: Its not working.. i used both the queries which you have suggested. All the values of date closed is appearing as null irrespective of the condition. But where as it is working if i give it like this.. (CASE WHEN A.C_STATUS='GR" THEN 1 END) AS DATE CLOSED. SO for this i am gettig the value as 1 for the rows which have status as green.. but when i replace the 1 with timestamp all the rows are coming null

Comment: Can you share the sample of the timestano you have?